# Extract distinct portions of long string with varying punctuation using RegEx

Tags: regex

I have a text file with many rows that generally follow the patterns shown below and I'd like to extract the segments numbered 1-4 in the image below. I cannot do it with Excel because the punctuation is not sufficiently consistent so I'd like to use RegEx.

[image: Instructions for parsing text]

I am looking for 4 distinct RegEx expressions, corresponding to the 4 items.

What I have so far:

- `(.+?(?=/))` gets me everything up to the `/` but I can't figure out how to split it in the Yellow and Cyan sections
- `(?<=\/\s)(.*)` gets me everything after the `/` but includes the Mintmark portion

Here is a good sample of the file contents:

```
Licinius II, AE follis, Alexandria. 316-317 AD. VAL CONSTANTINVS LICINIVS N CAES, laureate head right / IOVI CONSER-VATORI CAESS, Jupiter standing left, chlamys across left shoulder, holding Victory on globe and leaning on sceptre, eagle with wreath left. Left field: K. Right field: wreath over X over A. Mintmark ALE. RIC VII Alexandria 21.
Licinius II, AE follis, Alexandria. 316-317 AD. VAL CONSTANTINVS LICINIVS N CAES, laureate head right / IOVI CONSER-VATORI CAESS, Jupiter standing left, chlamys across left shoulder, holding Victory on globe and leaning on sceptre, eagle with wreath left. Left field: K. Right field: wreath over X over B. Mintmark ALE. RIC VII Alexandria 21.
Licinius II Follis. AD 317-320. DN VAL LICIN LICINIVS NOB C, laureate draped bust left, holding sceptre and mappa. / IOVI CONSER-VATORI CAESS, Jupiter standing left, chlamys across left shoulder, holding globe and sceptre. Crescent-B across fields. Mintmark SMAL. RIC VII Alexandria 25; Sear 15417.
Licinius II AE Follis. D N VAL LICIN LICINIVS NOB C, helmeted cuirassed bust left, holding spear and shield / IOVI CONSERVATORI, Jupiter standing left, holding Victory on globe and sceptre, eagle at foot left, captive to right, X over IIŒº (=12.5 denarii) in right field. Mintmark SMALA. RIC VII Alexandria 30; Cohen 21; Sear (1998) 3816 (not in new Sear).
Licinius II AE Follis. D N VAL LICIN LICINIVS NOB C, helmeted cuirassed bust left, holding spear and shield / IOVI CONSERVATORI, Jupiter standing left, holding Victory on globe and sceptre, eagle at foot left, captive to right, X over IIŒº (=12.5 denarii) in right field. Mintmark SMALB. RIC VII Alexandria 30; Cohen 21; Sear (1998) 3816 (not in new Sear).
Licinius II AE Follis of Antioch. AD 317-320. D N VAL LICIN LICINIVS NOB C, laureate, draped bust left, holding globe, sceptre and mappa / IOVI CONSERVATORI CAESS, Jupiter standing left, chlamys across left shoulder, holding Victory on globe and sceptre, captive standing left in left field, officina letter &Gamma in right field. Mintmark SMANT. RIC VII Antioch 29; Sear 15415.
Licinius II as Caesar, AE follis. D N VAL LICIN LICINIVS NOB C, diademed bust left with mappa and sceptre / IOVI CONS-ERVATORI CAESS Jupiter standing, head left, with Victory, captive at feet, Œî to right. Mintmark SMANT.
Licinius II AE Follis of Antioch. AD 317-320. D N VAL LICIN LICINIVS NOB C, laureate, draped bust left, holding globe, sceptre and mappa / IOVI CONSERVATORI CAESS, Jupiter standing left, chlamys across left shoulder, holding Victory on globe and sceptre, captive standing left in left field, officina letter Epsilon in right field. Mintmark SMANT. RIC VII Antioch 29; Sear 15415.
Licinius II AE follis. 317-320 AD. D N VAL LICIN LICINIVS NOB C, laureate, draped bust left, sceptre in left hand, mappa in right / IOVI CONSERVATORI CAESS, Jupiter standing left, chlamys across shoulder, leaning on sceptre, holding Victory on globe, captive at feet, I in right field. Mintmark SMANT.
Licinius II AE follis. 317-320 AD. D N VAL LICIN LICINIVS NOB C, laureate, draped bust left, sceptre in left hand, mappa in right / IOVI CONSERVATORI CAESS, Jupiter standing left, chlamys across shoulder, leaning on sceptre, holding Victory on globe, captive at feet, Z in right field. Mintmark SMANT.
Licinius II, Antioch, AE follis. D N VAL LICIN LICINIVS NOB C, Laureate bust left wearing imperial mantle and holding mappa, globe and sceptre / IOVI CONS-ERVATORI CAESS, Jupiter standing left, leaning on sceptre, Victory in right hand, captive at feet. Epsilon I in right field. Mintmark SMANT. RIC VII Antioch 29.
Licinius II AE follis of Antioch. 19mm, 3.025 g. DN VAL LICIN LICINIVS NOB C, laureate and draped bust left, holding globe, sceptre and mappa / IOVI CONS-ERVATORI CAESS, Jupiter standing left, chlamys over shoulder, holding Victory on globe and sceptre. Captive standing left in left field. H in right field. Mintmark SMATN. RIC VII Antioch 29 var (engraver's error, mintmark).
Licinius II, AV aureus, Antioch, AD 321-322. 21mm, 5.28 g. DN VAL LICIN LICINIVS NOB C, bare-headed, draped and cuirassed bust facing / IOVI CONSER-VATORI CAES, Jupiter, holding Victory on globe and sceptre seated facing on platform inscribed SIC V SIC X, eagle with wreath in beak to left. Star in right field. Mintmark SMAN Epsilon. RIC VII Antioch 33; Depeyrot 38/2; Calic√≥ 5153; Sear 15392.
Licinius II AE follis. 321-322 AD. D N VAL LICIN LICINIVS NOB C, helmeted, cuirassed bust left, holding spear and shield / IOVI CONS-ERVATORI, Jupiter standing left, chlamys across left shoulder, holding Victory on globe and eagle-tipped sceptre; eagle with wreath at foot left, captive to right. X over II Mu in right field, mintmark SMANTA.
Licinius II AE follis. 321-322 AD. D N VAL LICIN LICINIVS NOB C, helmeted, cuirassed bust left, holding spear and shield / IOVI CONS-ERVATORI, Jupiter standing left, chlamys across left shoulder, holding Victory on globe and eagle-tipped sceptre; eagle with wreath at foot left, captive to right. X over II Mu in right field, mintmark SMANTŒî.
Licinius II AE follis. 317 AD. LICINIVS IVN NOB CAES, laureate, cuirassed bust right / CONCORDIA AVGG N N, Concordia standing left, holding long caduceus and cornucopiae. Mintmark AQS. RIC VII Aquileia 12; Sear 15397.
Licinius II AE Follis. 320 AD. LICINIVS IVN NOB CAES, laureate, draped bust left, holding Victory and mappa / VIRTVS EXERCIT S-F, standard inscribed VOT X with captive seated on each side. Mintmark AQS.
Licinius II AE Follis of Aquileia. AD 320. LICINIVS IVN NOB CAES, laureate, draped bust left, holding Victory and mappa / VIRTVS-EXERCIT, Standard inscribed VOT XX with two captives seated at its base. S-F across fields. Mintmark AQS. RIC VII Aquileia 55; Sear 15473.
Licinius II, Aquileia, struck 320, AE follis. LICINIVS IVN NOB CAES, laureate, mantled bust left, holding globe and Victory / VIRTVS EXERCIT, standard with VOT XX, captives below, chi-rho in left field. Mintmark AQS. RIC VII Aquileia 59 var (unlisted for Licinius II).
Probus, AE antoninianus. Siscia mint. AD 278. IMP CM AVR PROBVS P AVG, radiate, cuirassed bust left, holding spear and shield / PM TRI P COS III PP, lion walking left, head of ox before it. Mintmark XXIT. Alfoeldi 44-14; RIC V-2 Siscia 615 var.
Probus, AE antoninianus. Siscia mint. IMP C PROBVS PF AVG, radiate, draped, cuirassed bust right / PM TRI P COS III PP, radiate lion walking right, thunderbolt in its jaws. Mintmark XXIQ. Cohen 457 var (bust type); Alf√∂ldi 47-1.
Probus AE Antoninianus, Siscia, 277 AD, 3.69 g. IMP PROBVS INV AVG, radiate, draped, cuirassed bust right / RESTIT ILIVRICI, two women as the personification of the Illyrian provinces standing, one facing left, raising hem of robe, standard behind her, one facing right, holding standard and raising right hand. Mintmark XXI. RIC 730 var (bust type); Alf√∂ldi 56/1.
Probus, AE antoninianus, Siscia. IMP PROBVS AVG, radiate bust left, wearing imperial mantle, holding eagle-tipped sceptre / SOLI INVICTO, Sol in quadriga galloping left, holding whip, raising right hand. Mintmark XXIQ. (This Siscia series not in RIC). Alf√∂ldi 76-60.
Probus, AE antoninianus. Siscia mint. IMP C M AVR PROBVS PF AVG, radiate, cuirassed bust left, holding spear over shoulder, head of Medusa facing on cuirass / SOLI INVICTO, Sol, holding whip, driving quadriga galloping left, all four horses facing forwards. Mintmark XXIP. Alf√∂ldi 76-125 var (cuirass type).
Probus, AE antoninianus. Siscia. IMP CM AVR PROBVS PF AVG, radiate bust left, wearing imperial mantle and holding eagle-tipped sceptre / SOLI INVICTO AVG, Sol, holding whip, in quadriga galloping left, all horses heads facing. Mintmark XXIV. Alf√∂ldi 78-1. Not in RIC.
Probus, AE antoninianus, Lyons. IMP C M AVR PROBVS AVG, radiate, cuirassed bust right / SECVRITAS ORBIS, Laetitia standing left, holding wreath and anchor. Mintmark I. Bastien supp. I and II 165a. Not in RIC.
Probus AV aureus. Ticinum. AD 276-282. IMP C M AVR PROBVS PF AVG, laureate, cuirassed bust right / CONSERVAT AVG, Sol standing front, looking left, naked but for chlamys over shoulder, holding globe and raising right hand. Mintmark SIS. RIC 307var; Calico 4152a.
Probus, AV aureus, 22mm, 5.98 g. AD 276¬ñ282. Siscia. IMP C M AVR PROBVS PF AVG, laureate bust left, wearing imperial mantle, holding eagle-tipped sceptre / HERCVLI ERYMANTHIO, Hercules, naked, standing front, holding the Erymanthian boar on his shoulder and lionskin over left arm. Not in RIC. Calic√≤ 4156 (this coin); Sear 11909 var (bust type): RIC 586 var; Cohen 272 var.
Probus AE Antoninianus. Siscia. IMP C PROBVS PF AVG, radiate, cuirassed bust right / AD LOCVTIO, emperor standing left on platform, a lictor at his side, soldiers on the ground to left and right. Cohen 277; Not in RIC.
Probus AV aureus. Siscia. IMP C M AVR PROBVS PF AVG, Radiate, helmeted and cuirassed bust left, holding spear and shield / PM TR I P, emperor, holding eagle-tipped sceptre and holding out right hand, driving quadriga stepping right. COS III below. Cohen 279.
Constantine AE follis. AD 322. CONSTAN-TINVS AVG, laureate head right. / DN CONSTANTINI MAX AVG, wreath within which is VOT XX, laurel branches to left and right. Mintmark AQP.
Constantine I, AE follis. AD 322. Aquileia. CONSTAN-TINVS AVG, laureate head right. / CAESARVM NOSTRORVM around VOT X within wreath. Mintmark AQT. RIC VII Aquileia 105 var (officina).
Constantine I, Aquileia. AD 330-335. CONSTANTI-NVS MAX AVG, rosette-diademed, draped, cuirassed bust right. / GLOR-IA EXERC-ITVS, two soldiers holding spears and shields with two standards between them, O on banners. Mintmark: AQP. RIC VII Aquileia 118.   Text    Full Size
Constantine I AE follis. 334-335 AD. CONSTANTINVS MAX AVG, rosette-diademed, draped and cuirassed bust right. / GLORIA EXERCITVS, two soldiers standing facing each other, two standards between, o on banners, cross in centre, mintmark AQS.  Text    Full Size
Constantine I, AE follis, Aquileia. AD 330-335. CONSTANTI-NVS MAX AVG, rosette-diademed, draped, cuirassed bust right. / GLOR-IA EXERC-ITVS, two soldiers holding spears and shields with two standards between them. F in lower centre. Mintmark: AQS. RIC VII Aquileia 131.   Text    Full Size
Constantine, Aquileia, AE follis. 335-337 AD. CONSTANTI-NVS MAX AVG, rosette-diademed, draped, cuirassed bust right. / GLOR-IA EXERC-ITVS, two soldiers with spears and shields; one standard between them with o on banner. Mintmark AQS. RIC VII Aquileia 139.
```

Comment: Please give us a _minimal_ reproducible example.  What is the smallest text which demonstrates the logic for capturing the 4 lines?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I updated the inquiry to give more detail. I'm not looking for actual code, i.e. Python. I am looking for the RegEx expressions that I can test out in places like  https://regexr.com/

Comment: The problem is that it's far more easier to give you a code - and far more easier to do it with one single regular expression for extracting all segments - than giving an expression for each segment which is not capturing anything else. If you need to extract all - why you need regex for each segment separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a single pattern with 4 capturing groups.

```
\.\s*([A-Z]+(?:[\s-][A-Z]+)*),([^/]+)/\s*([A-Z]+(?:[\s-][A-Z]+)*),(.*?)(?:\.|mintmark)
```

*In parts*

- `\.\s*` Match `.` and optional whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[A-Z]+(?:[\s-][A-Z]+)*` Match the uppercase chars divided by a space or `-`
- `)` Close group 1
- `,` Match a comma
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `[^/]+` Match 1+ times any char except `/`
- `)` Close group 2
- `/\s*` Match `/` and 1+ whitespace chars
- `(` Caputure **group 3**

  - `[A-Z]+(?:[\s-][A-Z]+)*` Match the uppercase chars divided by a space or `-`
- `)` Close group 3
- `,` Match a comma
- `(.*?)` Capture **group 4**, match any char as least as possible
- `(?:\.|mintmark)` Match either a `.` or `mintmark` using a case insensitive match

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/29MDfp/1)

As you can see, it only does not match this line as there is no comma after the second sequence of capitals.

```
 Constantine I, AE follis. AD 322. Aquileia. CONSTAN-TINVS AVG, laureate head right. / CAESARVM NOSTRORVM around VOT X within wreath. Mintmark AQT. RIC VII Aquileia 105 var (officina).
```

Comment: This is fantastic! Thank you @the-fourt-bird. How would I go about modifying the regex if I wanted: 1) capture group 4 to always go up to (but exclude) the word 'mintmark' if it's there, or go till the end of the line if it is not, and 2) create capture group 5 to capture anything after the word 'mintmark' up to the subsequent period character? If you'd prefer I ask this as a separate post, I am happy to do so. Many, many thanks!